# Interface Builder can't see classes in a static library

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, static-libraries

I have refactored some UIView sub-classes into a static library. However, when using Interface Builder to create view components for a project that uses the static library I find that it is unaware of the library classes. What do I need to do to make the class interfaces visible to Interface Builder?

**Update:** The correct answer refers to dragging the headers into the 'XIB browser'. The '.h' files can be dragged from a finder window to the window area identified in this image:

[alt text http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/1221/xibbrowser.png](http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/1221/xibbrowser.png)

Comment: good question, good solution - thanks Teabot and Reed Olsen!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try dragging the static library into your xib browser in Interface Builder. I haven't tried this with a static library, but the concept is the same. When you drag header files into IB, you can access those classes.

Comment: Dragging the header files directly into the XIBs browser/explorer worked - dragging the static library did not.

Answer (score 4):

LexH, try linking with the -ObjC flag when building your static library.  That worked for me... for about a year :-)  I found this post as the problem has returned with a fresh OSX install and an upgrade in xcode.  But it worked in XCode 3.1.2.

- David

Answer (score 1):

Add the same problem as LexH. It worked only when I called a dummy class method.
The problem was that I did not add my static library to the "link binary with libraries" under target.
Strangely everything else worked.

I followed this guide to link with my static lib [Create static lib](http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2009/02/08/creating-a-static-library-for-iphone.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Dragging the library or headers to XIB Browser didn't work. Read Class Files didn't work. So I called:

```
[MyLibraryClass version];    // Substitute your class name for "MyLibraryClass".
```

This worked. version is a class method of NSObject, so all subclasses of NSObject inherit it.