# How to add to Interface builder classes in a static library, permanently?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, static-libraries, permanent

I know the thread on [Interface Builder can't see classes in a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058766/interface-builder-cant-see-classes-in-a-static-library)
there add to InterfaceBuilder(IB) classes in static library, temporary.
The way is drag & drop the header files(.h).
It's working in one time booting the IB

I wanna permanently add to IB the classes.

How to do this?

Comment: When I maked new class kind of UIViewController inherit a class in my static-library,
Then the class has no view outlet.

How to work in every new class inherit a class in static-library ?

Answer (score 0):

In short, I'm not aware of any solution.  Typically Read class Files... menu item in IB is sufficient to make IB aware of classes in static libraries.