# Interface Builder is not able to find classes in a static library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

Interface Builder is not able to find classes in a static library. It is throwing **Unknown `MyClassName` in Interface Builder** error when I run the application. Please note that I am using this class in the controller but still seeing this behavior in Xcode 4.6+.

This solution works but I can't add 30+ categories for as many classes in the static library. It looks uglier when you have multiple static libraries: *[Xcode 4, Interface Builder and the Awareness of Classes in a Static Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707201/xcode-4-interface-builder-and-the-awareness-of-classes-in-a-static-library)*

The best one I've been able to find so far is to add `[MyClassName class];` calls in my main method for each one of the static library classes to force Xcode to load them but again it requires all those "class" statements in the main which I am trying to avoid.

Adding "all_load" to linker flag works too but causes tons of files getting included in the build.

Just wondering if anybody knows of a better and cleaner way to deal with this mess?