# XIB can't locate class in static library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, xcode5

I have a static library with a value transformer class in it.

I have a XIB that is trying to use that transformer in bindings.

I get a runtime error: Cocoa Bindings: Cannot find value transformer with name [MyTransformerClassName]

The library is linked in the build settings-- other classes from that library compile fine.  How do I get the transformer working?  The XIB is the only place its used.

There is this OLD question, but it doesn't seem relevant to XCode 5:
[Interface Builder can't see classes in a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058766/interface-builder-cant-see-classes-in-a-static-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh.  Found it.

Needed to use the `-ObjC` flag in "Other Linker Flags" in the project's Build Settings.  This gets the linker to build everything in the library.

Mentioned here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/configuration.html